# Why is total number of file descriptors in the system not increasing after fork()?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I first created a lot of file descriptors in my program, and I see the number of system file descriptors go up on my system:

```
# bash(1) before:
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
1024    0   97861
```

```
# bash (2): create a lot of fds
>>> a = []
>>> while True:
...   a.append(open('asdf', 'a'))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'asdf'
>>>
```

As expected, the number of file descriptors goes up:

```
# back to bash (1) output
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
2048    0   97861
```

Now, if I fork() inside python, I expected the kernel to copy all these fds in the child too- but this doesn't seem to increase the number in `file-nr`?

```
# bash (2): more commands at python- fork a child
>>> import os
>>> import time
>>> if os.fork() == 0:
...   time.sleep(1000)
... else:
...   time.sleep(1000)
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file-nr` shows the number of open *files*, from the kernel’s perspective (this corresponds to [open file descriptions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_258), which are kernel data structures, rather than [file descriptors](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_166), which are per-process). Forking doesn’t open any new files, so the number in `file-nr` doesn’t increase.

Comment: As in: the fork copies the `references` to the files. If this was not true, the parent and child would not share the same files, so they would not be able to communicate through anonymous pipes.